# Shopify: Add scope without interrupting existing App users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, shopify-app

I have a Shopify App that deals with products and shipping. The current scope is:

```
scope = ["read_shipping", "write_shipping", "read_products"]
```

New functionality needs new scope as:

```
scope = ["read_shipping", "write_shipping", "read_products",
  "write_products", "read_inventory", "write_inventory",
  "read_fulfillments", "write_fulfillments", "read_price_rules",
  "write_price_rules"]
```

For new App users everything is fine. How do I introduce this new scope to existing App users by:

- Requesting App users to accept the new scope permissions
- Not interrupting existing functionality for App users who never end up accepting new scope permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the new scopes you need to your App. Whenever ANYONE re-authenticates they will be prompted by Shopify to accept the new scopes. That is the only way to do it. No you cannot sneak in new scopes with existing installs, hoping they will just **get** the new scopes without them knowing about it.

Comment: thanks @David Lazar. My question  - maybe poorly worded - was about how to re-authenticate. I would like my App users to know what scope permissions they are granting. 

For existing app users I first detected allowed scope, for any apps that did not have the required scope I then requested they re-authenticate. It appears to work.

Comment: Whenever you change scope, Shopify will offer up the re-authenticate automatically. You do nothing special but change scope. I did answer your question.

Comment: I added new scopes to my application controller and subsequently created a new controller and view that used one of these new scopes. When an existing app user tried to access the new view and controller we receive a 401 Forbidden error. It was only when I detected the existing app users scopes...and then triggered re-authentication...was I able to get it to work. 

I did not see any automatic reauthentication. I followed Step 2 here: https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth#step-2-ask-for-permission to request permission.

Comment: Whatever. If you requested App views and were already authenticated, of course you would not be prompted. It is only when you visit the App fresh and clean with no session that oAuth would present Shopify with the new scope, and forthwith the challenge to accept the new scopes.